# Segmentation fault for lambda function in non-static data member initializer

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer

I am unsure about a possible GCC bug in initialization of a `std::function` from a lambda function capturing `this` in a non-static data member initializer. Is this allowed by the C++ standard or is this UB?

Given the following code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A {
      T x = 0;
      std::function<void(T)> f = [this](T v) { x = v; };
};

int main() {
      A<int> a;
      a.f(1);
      std::cout << a.x << "\n";
}
```

In my understanding, it should print `1`. However, when built with GCC 5.4.0 or GCC 6.2.0, `a.f(1)` emits a segmentation fault, because the captured `this` pointer is null.

The following alternatives work as I expected:

- Using constructor initializer list:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  struct B {
      B() : f([this](T v) { x = v; }) {}
      T x = 0;
      std::function<void(T)> f;
  };
  ```
- Without template:

  ```
  struct C {
      int x = 0;
      std::function<void(int)> f = [this](int v) { x = v; };
  };
  ```

Also, when built with Clang 3.8.0, all three versions behave as I expect, which doesn't mean it is not UB.

Comment: I'm leaning towards a GCC bug : `this` shouldn't *ever* be null.

Comment: I'm wondering what VS2015 does :) Can someone check please?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Works on MSVS 2015 update 3.

Comment: Seems weird to me that you can even capture this like that.

Comment: @ViktorSehr Why is that? `std::function<void(T)> f = [this](T v) { x = v; };` is just syntactic sugar for `f([this](T v) { x = v; })`

Comment: I didn't even thought that code was possible

Comment: Notes that are not directly about the bug you spotted: that one danger is that `f` captures `this` by pointer.  It is then copied whenever `A` is copied.  So `A<int> a = A<int>{};` can (in C++14 or 11) have an `a.f()` that follows a dangling pointer.  (And in general this can happen in other cases).  Second, note that ODR violations are really easy here (but I think the standard is working to patch them), what is the type of the object stored within `f`?  The same or different in two source files that include the above header?

Comment: @Yakk, about the ODR, the type should be the same in all translation units (`std::function<void(T)>`), the difference is only in the returning type of the initializer expression, not in the data member type. I believe the compiler has the freedom to generate a slightly different version of the implicit constructor in each TU, but all of them are equivalent and interchangeable (the internal type might be different in instances created from different TUs, but that is just an implementation detail). So I think there is no violation of the ODR here.

Comment: @AndréSassi Not `std::function`'s type, but the type of the thing *stored within std::function*, which is exposed through `std::function`'s interface.  The problem is that the code run in your constructor that constructs the `std::function` in its initializer list *differs between translation units*, which is an ODR violation.

Comment: @Yakk, I was considering the type of the thing within to be an implementation detail, because I wasn't aware of `std::function::target_type()`, which exposes it. So yes, different TUs might (if the implementation defines each lambda type independently of enclosing class type) construct objects `a` and `b` such that `a.f.target_type() != b.f.target_type()`.

Comment: @andre the problem is the ODR doesn't say "oh well, you get different versions" but "program ill formed no diagnostic required".

Comment: This is probably a compiler bug. Please file a ticket treating it as such. I can't see anything wrong here (indicating Clang & VS are correct), or anything that should differ between brace-or-equal initialisation & the in-constructor form (indicating GCC is buggily inconsistent). The draft Standard I have here, N4594, just says "A brace-or-equal-initializer for a non-static data member specifies a default member initializer for the member". Member initialisers can get the value of `this`. It doesn't say brace-or-equal initialisers are unable to use `this` or any other difference. Why would it?

Comment: Further reason to [go to the GCC Bugzilla and report this as a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc): on another GCC version, the code explicitly causes an internal compiler error and... asks the user to file a bug. See this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621477/segmentation-fault-for-lambda-function-in-non-static-data-member-initializer/39633433?noredirect=1#comment66615448_39633433

Comment: @underscore_d, thanks. I think you are right, the inconsistency between the two initializer forms suggests its really a bug. I'm already in the proccess to file the bug report (account creation there seems to be manual due to spam), then I'll post the link to the report here.

Comment: @AndréSassi Cool, thanks!

Comment: @AndréSassi Have you succeeded in filing a bug report? No link here so far.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    T x = 0;
    std::function<void(T)> f = [this](T v) { x = v; };
};
```

As `this` does not exist when you define `f`. You need to initilize `f` in a constructor, such as:

```
A(){ f = [this](T v){ x=v; } }
```

It worked with G++4.8.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles and runs on VS2015 (windows).
So this is probably a compiler error.

Also, if you will remove the template it works on http://cpp.sh/
Try this code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
      int x = 0;
      std::function<void(int)> f = [this](int v) { x = v; };
};

int main() {
      A  a;
      a.f(1);
      std::cout << a.x << "\n";
}
```

running original code on  cpp.sh gives:

```
 internal compiler error: in tsubst_copy, at cp/pt.c:12569
Please submit a full bug report
```

So I guess it's a bug

Comment: whether something does or does not work on VS usually doesn't indicate much useful about that thing's legality... :P and cpp.sh uses GCC 4.9.2, but since you changed the code, i'm not sure that means much either.

Comment: running original code on  cpp.sh gives:7:35: internal compiler error: in tsubst_copy, at cp/pt.c:12569
Please submit a full bug report, So I guess it's a bug

Comment: Thanks for that. Hopefully the OP will [go to the GCC Bugzilla and report it as such](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc).